# Django get object and relation field of a ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I was wondering if this can be done with a single query

My `models.py` has a model that has a M2M with itself

```
class Person(models.Model):
    objectid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField()
    relations = models.ManyToManyField(
        self, 
        on_delete = models.CASCADE, 
        through = Person_Person, #This lets you define the model that will act as an intermadiary
        symmetrical = False, #This needs to be set with recursive relationships
    )

class Person_Person(models.Model):
    cod_person_1 = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_cod_person_1')
    cod_person_2 = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_cod_person_2')
    relation = models.IntegerField(choices =             
        ((0, 'Parent'),
        (1, 'Child'),
        (2, 'Engaged'),
        (3, 'Widow'),
        (4, 'Related')),
    default = 4)
```

Then I added this function to `Person` model to get all related `Person`

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    def getRelated(self):
        return self.relations.all()
```

`self.relations.all()` returns me a `QuerySet` with `Person` objects, but I also need to get the `relation` field from `Person_Person` with it

It doesn't really matter if I get the object itself, all I need are the field values.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships and especially "If you need to access a membership’s information you may do so by directly querying the Membership model:"

Answer (score 2):

You can get those instances explicitly, while also making use of [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related):

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_related(self):
        qs = Person_Person.objects.select_related('cod_person_2')
        return qs.filter(cod_person_1=self)
```

Comment: Thas is exactly what I was looking for, but shouldn't the filter be cod_person_1 = self.pk?

Comment: You don't actually have to do this, Django automatically will use `instance.pk` in that case. But you can write that explicitly, if you want to.

Comment: @Mojimi or you can simply do `self.person_person_set.all()`